# macOS Catalina - Spotlight Search Problem with External Hard Drive Mac OS Extended (Journaled)

Tags: hard-drive, catalina, external-disk, spotlight

I have an external hard drive that I am having trouble with in Catalina.

The drive mounts properly but Spotlight will not search it.

The drive formatted as Mac OS Extended (Journaled) and is set up to potentially be a boot drive.

But. I just want to mount the drive and search it. Spotlight will not search it.

Is there an issue with Mac OS Extended (Journaled) format at Catalina?
Or something I am not thinking about?

It is kind of driving me crazy.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the problem seems to have been with the Mac OS Extended (Journaled) format. I spoke to two Apple Geniuses (head supervisors). No one could explain why this was happening. But I decided to wipe the drive, reformat the disk, and put everything back on it.

Comment: Any update on this? Have you managed to get it working ?